# Regression Error in R forecasting

Tags: r, regression

I'm doing a simple forecast model in R for GDP (PIB), but I'm getting the following error when executing the regression:

**Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ t2, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : variable lengths differ (found for 't')**

Follows the Scrip:

```
scan=(~pib)

#Forecast

tspib = ts(pib[,2],start = c(2002,1), frequency = 12)

tspib

plot(tspib, xlab='Years', ylab = "Pib")

plot(forecast(tspib))

summary(forecast(tspib))

#Regr

length(tspib)

t=(1:182)

t

t2=t^2

#Error
reg=lm(y~t+t2)

summary(reg)
```

The file is a CSV in my pc, follow the 5 first lines:

```
Date    PIB
2002-01 112374,80
2002-02 111477,10
2002-03 118444,70
2002-04 120385,90
2002-05 123552,50
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: where is the variable named y?

Comment: try `t=(1:nrow(pib))` to replace `t=(1:182)` If that does not work, what nrow(pib) gives you ?

Comment: @Imo, I set the variable y to y = pib$PIB, then it went ok...i think that was the problem. Thanks!